# how to use sunsupot-rails with rails 2.3.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

i cloned the project that consists of rails 2.3.14, and sunspot-rails 1.2.1 how can i configure sunspot for this project?any help

Regards
Ateq

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Here are the docs https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/README.md#quickstart-with-rails-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure sunspot-rails by going through [github.com/outoftime/sunspot](https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot) tutorial.

Hopefully, this will be helpful for you.